# NSPredicate for entities that have at least one related entity with attribute value

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

This may be answered elsewhere but I wasn't able to find an answer. I have a `Speaker` entity with a to-many relationship to `Speech` objects. How can I write a predicate that will fetch all the `Speakers` that only have `Speech` objects with an `audioURL` attribute?

There are a few things I've tried, basically tweaking the following predicate:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Speaker"];
NSPredicate *predicate;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"speech.audioURL != nil  AND  speech.audioURL != ''"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put differently, you want to fetch `Speakers` where NONE of their `Speech` objects has `audioURL` == "" and NONE of their `Speech` objects has `audioURL` == nil:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Speaker"];
NSPredicate *predicate;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(NONE speech.audioURL == nil) AND (NONE speech.audioURL == '')"];
```

**EDIT**

But having tested this, CoreData seems to interpret NONE as ANY NOT rather than ALL NOT.  So instead, use SUBQUERY:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(speech, $s, $s.audioURL == nil OR $s.audioURL == '').@count == 0"];
```

This handles those cases where the `Speaker`'s speeches, if they exist, meet the criteria.  If you also want to exclude those Speakers that have no speeches, add another clause:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(speech.@count > 0) AND (SUBQUERY(speech, $s, $s.audioURL == nil OR $s.audioURL == '').@count == 0)"];
```